# How to remove backslashes in strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As an output of Pytesseract, I get a string variable which contains backslashes. I would like to remove all of the back slashes.

'13, 0\\'70'

Unforturnately the replace function does not work as the string doesn't seem to be an actual string when the variable value is copied. Anybody knows how I can remove all the backslashes?

[image]

Comment: The code you give is not legal Python; you have an unmatched single-quote.

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: `brut_mass = '13, 0\\'70'` isn't valid syntax. If it were `13, 0\'70'` that would just be the backslash escaping the internal quote.

Comment: Yes. I figured it is not legal Python but that is the output I get out of Pytesseract which stores it as a string.

Comment: I think @Prune below got it right. Your question shows that you did `brut_mass = '13, 0\\'70'` but I think that you really got the string some other way and you are trying to get back to the original string from pytesseract's represenation of the string.

Comment: Exactly *what* does it store as a string?  The assignment you posted is not Python code.

Comment: Can you give us the result of `print(repr(brut_mass))` ? that should help figure this out.

Comment: It gives "13.0'70" as results @tdelaney

Comment: Fixed it with repr(brut_mass).replace(" ' ", '')! Thanks!

Comment: That should leave extra unwanted double quotes on each end of the string. Perhaps `brut_mass.replace(" ' ", '')` is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your outermost quotation marks with double-quotes, and then properly applied `replace:

```
>>> brut_mass = "13, 0\\'70"
>>> brut_mass.replace('\\', '')
"13, 0'70"
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: If your actual string is "'13, 0\\'70'", my method still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the code below.

```
brut_mass = repr(brut_mass).replace(" ' ", '')
```

or alternatively to avoid the double quotations

```
brut_mass = brut_mass.replace(" ' ", '')
```